# Setting xlwings properties freezes or does not work

Tags: excel, freeze, deprecated, xlwings

I have been trying to format an excel spreadsheet using the xlwings module. On another thread on SO, I found a series of formatting & printing properties to play with. Unfortunately, page_setup does not seem to work and ws.api.View seems to make the whole process hang forever.

```py
import xlwings as xw

# Create or modify the excel spreadsheet
    with xw.App(visible=False) as app:
   
        if os.path.exists(classroom_file):
            wb = xw.Book(classroom_file)
        else:
            wb = xw.Book()

        # Selecting a sheet
        ws = xw.sheets[0]
        
        # Page setup
        ws_ps = ws.page_setup

        # Properties
        ws_ps.LeftMargin = 0.75
        ws_ps.RightMargin = 0.75
        ws_ps.TopMargin = 1
        ws_ps.BottomMargin = 1
        ws_ps.HeaderMargin = 0.5
        ws_ps.FooterMargin = 0.5
        ws_ps.PrintHeadings = False
        ws_ps.PrintGridlines = False
        ws_ps.PrintComments = xw.constants.PrintLocation.xlPrintNoComments
        ws_ps.PrintQuality = 600
        ws_ps.CenterHorizontally = True
        ws_ps.CenterVertically = True
        ws_ps.Draft = False
        ws_ps.PaperSize = xw.constants.PaperSize.xlPaperLetter
        ws_ps.FirstPageNumber = xw.constants.Constants.xlAutomatic
        ws_ps.Order = xw.constants.Order.xlDownThenOver
        ws_ps.BlackAndWhite = False
        ws_ps.PrintErrors = xw.constants.PrintErrors.xlPrintErrorsDisplayed
        ws_ps.OddAndEvenPagesHeaderFooter = False
        ws_ps.DifferentFirstPageHeaderFooter = False
        ws_ps.ScaleWithDocHeaderFooter = True
        ws_ps.AlignMarginsHeaderFooter = True

        ws.api.View = xw.constants.xlPageLayoutView

        # rest of the code filling up the spreadsheet (working & tested separately). e.g.,
        ws.range("A1:A2").value = [["Column1"],["Column2"]]
        ws.range('A1').api.Font.Bold = True
        ws.range('A1').api.Font.Size = 15
        # ...

        if os.path.exists(classroom_file):
            wb.save()
        else:
            wb.save(os.path.abspath(classroom_file))
        wb.close()
```

I tried to comment / uncomment one line at a time to see if any were working, looked at the scarce xlwings documentation and examples on xlwings, and experimented/compared it directly with VBA (as I understand it, xlwings is a VBA wrapper).

It took me a long time but I found some equivalents and wanted to share them since it could be useful to others. (I'd love to hear of any other ways to do this)

Answer (score 1):

It seems like xlwings has gone through a lot of changes over the years. While a previous user. ws.page_setup just never worked for me no matter how hard I tried.

However, it is possible to make direct VBA calls through the api module:

1. most VBA constants are defined in classes in [constant.py](https://github.com/xlwings/xlwings/blob/b83ff923a952d1a8893c2d4dd56d468fe9a5dd51/xlwings/constants.py). They are called through xlwings.constants.CLASS_NAME.VARIABLE_NAME
2. page related properties are set through the xlwings.sheets[index].api.PageSetup.PROPERTY_NAME
3. window related properties are set through the xlwings.App.api.ActiveWindow.PROPERTY_NAME

Here is an example of the properties that worked for me in the current xlwings module (0.30.9):

```html
import xlwings as xw

with xw.App(visible=False) as app:

    # Changing window related properties
    app.api.ActiveWindow.DisplayGridlines = False
    app.api.ActiveWindow.View = xw.constants.WindowView.xlPageLayoutView

    # Changing page related properties
    ws.api.PageSetup.Orientation = xw.constants.PageOrientation.xlLandscape
    ws.api.PageSetup.PaperSize = xw.constants.PaperSize.xlPaperLetter
    ws.api.PageSetup.Zoom = 75

    # draw borders around a range of cells
    cells = ws.range((6,1),(25,17))
    cells.api.Borders.LineStyle=1
    cells.api.Borders.Weight = 2

    wb.save()
    wb.close()
```

Do you know more types of properties and how to make an api call to them?